# How to disable pretty-print in Safari inspector?

Tags: safari, web-inspector

Pretty-print is always on by default. How do I make it be off by default?

Comment: This question is very similar to [this one][1]. You may find your answer here.      [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403083/ios-xml-pretty-print

Comment: It's not the same question. I just want to know if it's possible to turn this setting off (so it stays of by default) in the Safari inspector. Every time I open the inspector, the setting is always turned on, which I don't like.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot disable it. Because the inspector is showing computed DOMs of rendered HTML (with JavaScript and CSS), it is a different thing from original HTML source code (but sometimes looked like the same one). So it is not just pretty-printed.

If you would like to get source code of the web page, see instructions below.

https://ccm.net/faq/33026-safari-view-the-source-code-of-a-webpage